# Adding chef cookbooks from github

Tags: chef-infra

I've downloaded a number of cookbooks from the opscode site using the command: **knife cookbook site install git** for example. However now I would like to download a cookbook from a repository on github into my current cookbooks directory. How should I go about doing this? should I just clone the repository into my cookbooks directory?

Thank you!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You coould install the knife github plugin from https://github.com/websterclay/knife-github-cookbooks, after which you could simply use `knife cookbook github install cookbooks/yum` to install yum from https://github.com/cookbooks/yum.

However, I would suggest using Librarian-Chef from https://github.com/applicationsonline/librarian, it works pretty much like bundler does for ruby gems (if you're familiar with that).

Edit: Since this apparently still receives views, I would be remiss not to mention [berkshelf](http://berkshelf.com/), which is amazing.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. For the first method, let's say I wanted to install the elastic search cookbook from here: https://github.com/karmi/cookbook-elasticsearch. Would I do something like this: **knife cookbook github install karmi/cookbook-elasticsearch**?  Also, Librarian looks nice, but I'm a little lost. I'm familiar with bundler, but I've been following a tutorial that's using *knife cookbook install...*...I want to keep all the cookbooks in the same repository. Sorry, I'm at my day job, so can't try this out yet.

Comment: What if I simply downloaded the cookbook in the cookbooks folder? Let's say I already have a bunch of cookbooks downloaded in a folder called **chef-repo** (the name of the respository from opscode). But there are other repositories with cookbooks. Can I just download the cookbook (as a zip maybe) and add it to the cookbooks folder? I can't see why this wouldn't work. The drawback is that I won't get the updates from the original upstream repo though.

Comment: I noticed when using the **knife-github-cookbooks** plugin, from the github description it says: *The repo at https://github.com/cookbooks/yum will be cloned into a temporary directory, moved into cookbooks/yum* So should I be in my **chef-repo** repository when running this command? Isn't this creating a new sub repository first, then copying back the cookbook to my *cookbooks* folder?

Comment: Right, `knife cookbook github install karmi/cookbook-elasticsearch` would be correct.

All it does is create a directory for the cookbook (and a branch in your repository I believe), so you can absolutely use it when you want to store all your cookbooks in chef-repo.
You could also download everything by hand, the plugin just makes it easier and has a few other tools, like `knife cookbook github compare` to compare your local version to the upstream version.

Comment: Keeping all cookbooks in the same repository makes it a bit harder to track changes to individual cookbooks, and to update individual cookbooks.
But I guess it's a decent enough solution when you're just starting out and keeping everything small!

Answer (score 8):

To download and manage cookbooks, you could use **Berkshelf** which comes with a way in itself to manage the cookbook dependencies by itself. If you are familiar with Ruby, it works like Gemfile.
  You could download cookbooks from github by adding this command in your BerksFile

> cookbook 'nginx' , path : ' github url for cookbook'

Comment: cookbook 'mysql', git: 'git://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/mysql.git'

Comment: Even shorter: cookbook 'nginx', github: 'username/nginx'

Answer (score -1):

You can Try this command

```
knife cookbook site download cookbookname
```

Comment: From [the documentation for `knife cookbook site`](https://docs.chef.io/knife_cookbook_site.html): "The knife cookbook site subcommand is used to interact with cookbooks that are located at https://supermarket.chef.io."