# Configuration for location of Chef cookbooks?

Tags: chef-infra

As I understand it `knife cookbook site install XYZ` searches and installs cookbooks from http://community.opscode.com.

According to http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Managing+Cookbooks+With+Knife:

> Cookbook Site
>
> The cookbook site sub-commands are meant for interacting with the community cookbook site: community.opscode.com.

Is this source 'hard coded' into Chef? Can I configure this in `knife.rb`? (Would I want to?)

(I ran `ack` inside the `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/chef-10.12.0` directory on my system and didn't see any code that mentioned `community.opscode.com`, so I'm not sure how `knife` would even know where to look.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the correct understanding.  There is currently no other community site for chef cookbooks, so you would most likely not want to change that URL.  However, there are [knife plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11113224/adding-chef-cookbooks-from-github) that you could use in order to download cookbooks from other locations, such as github.

Comment: BTW, I found the code that defines the cookbook source: `cookbook_site_download.rb`: `def cookbooks_api_url; 'http://cookbooks.opscode.com/api/v1/cookbooks' end`. I didn't find it originally because it doesn't match 'community'.